# Can not run a completed application outside of development environment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I have just finished fully debugging a new application and want to give it to a couple of people to check out. It is an app developed in Visual Studio Community 2017. It uses Entity Framework 6.2.0.  When I run it in VS2017 it works fine. When I run it from the file manager I get this error: `"Could not load file or assembly Entity Framework, Version=6.0.0.0... or one of its dependencies. The system  cannot find the file specified."`

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Entity Framework, but it doesn't solve my problem.
Can somebody give me a place to look for my problem? Thank you.

Comment: Have you deployed / copied ALL files from your build, including all dll files? Or did you try running your application only using the .exe file?

Comment: I didn't copy the application anywhere. I just try to run the program \obj\debug directory.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are experiencing means that it cannot find the entity framework DLL, you can try checking where it is looking for the file,

You can try going to your build properties in visual studio and tick the Entity Framework DLL as Always Copy to output Path(I.E copy local)

[image: Build Local]

a great way to do that is to use [FusionLog.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer)

The snipped from the linked address explain what it is.

> The Assembly Binding Log Viewer displays details for assembly binds.
>   This information helps you diagnose why the .NET Framework cannot
>   locate an assembly at run time. These failures are usually the result
>   of an assembly deployed to the wrong location, a native image that is
>   no longer valid, or a mismatch in version numbers or cultures. The
>   common language runtime's failure to locate an assembly typically
>   shows up as a TypeLoadException in your application.

The idea is to run it as admin, set a custom log path and run your application, if there are issues in the application, you can double click on it and check the resulting web page that shows you why the assembly binding failed and what path it was looking for.

Comment: I try using Assembly Binding Log Viewer, but could not get any output information. But, when I tried to run app now in the developing environment I get the error there. I now get a ($exception).FusionLog error that look the output from the assembly binding log view. It look like it looking for EntityFramework.DLL and EntityFramework.EXE in the same directory as my app.  I can not locate EntityFramework.EXE, where would that come from?

Comment: OK, thank to your help I now understand what going on. Here is what I found out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thank to your help I now understand what's going on. Here is what I found out.

1. If you look at the properties for References/EntityFramework the default location the application look for EntityFramework is taken from the Properties/Path if the Properties/CopyLocal equal false.
2. If I want to see the same error I was getting INSIDE of the development environment, I needed to change the Properties/CopyLocal to equal true and then recompile the program. If I then run the program I will get ($exception).FusionLog error that help with trying to explain what was going on.
3. In order to run my program from the file manager I had to change the Properties/CopyLocal to equal true, recompile the program, and copy EntityFramework.DLL to the directory where the program exist.